# Fastest way to draw a grid c#

Tags: c#, wpf

At the moment I am drawing a grid of "cells" (each cell is unique - different colours, borders etc) using a WPF window, with a Grid and binding a list of Cells to an ItemsControl ItemSource.

...this is slow, really slow.  Takes a couple of seconds to render.  Is there a faster way I could draw such a grid?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CellTemplate">  
        <local:CellImage Width="10" Height="10" CellProperty="{Binding}"></local:CellImage>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="WholeTemplate">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CellTemplate}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid Name="WholeGrid">
    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="WholeGrid" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource WholeTemplate}">
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And the binding:

```
        List<List<Cell>> lsts = new List<List<Cell>>();
        WholeGrid.ItemsSource = lsts;
```

Comment: How about using a `DataGrid`?

Comment: I tried a datagrid - it had a similar issue.  Just took a long while to render

Comment: Can you post your code? Do you create the grid in XAML or are you manually constructing it in C#?

Comment: Post your code or create a [MCVE]

Comment: Down votes slightly harsh...but I have added some code in (question wasn't that complex was it?)

Comment: Still no clear indication what you're doing here. How many Cells, and what do they do/hold?

Answer (score 1):

Change your stack panel to  VirtualizingStackPanel like this

```
ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CellTemplate}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Then it will only draw those items visible and should be much quicker, and as you scroll it should draw as many as it needs.